# babel secondary languages cause conflicts due to shorthands

Tags: listings, babel

Why do secondary babel languages make their shorthand characters active? Is there a way to make them only active for their language, instead of making them active characters that output themselves, to avoid conflicts?

In the following MWE, adding `german` as a secondary language (without activating it) *breaks* the document, because shortcut character `"` is made active and because my definition of `\code` is a bad idea (but hard to fix*). I can use `shorthands=off`, but then shortcuts aren't available in German.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{%
    \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]^#1^}

\begin{document}
The " character is active: \verb!\the\catcode`"! = \the\catcode`" .
But shortcuts are not actually active: "s.
\\

\shorthandoff{"}
I must disable shortcuts to ensure that " is not active: \verb!\the\catcode`"! =
\the\catcode`" .
So I can use the \verb!\code! command: \code{"bar" + str1}.
\\

\shorthandon{"}
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
Text with German shortcuts: "s.
\end{otherlanguage}
\shorthandoff{"}
\end{document}
```

*IIUC fixing the abuse would force me to change the syntax of `\code`, and that would require changing tens of pages using `\code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `\code` is wrong: just avoid grabbing the argument. This way you will have available the full power of `\lstinline`, so typing either `\code{<tokens>}` or `\code|<tokens>|` (where `|` is any character not appearing in `<tokens>`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]}

\begin{document}
The " character is active: \verb!\the\catcode`"! = \the\catcode`" .
But shortcuts are not actually active: "s.

So I can use the \verb!\code! command: \code{"bar" + str1}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
Text with German shortcuts: "s.
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `\lstinline{...}` is documented as experimental, but this seems to work.

I guess there's no straightforward way to automatically make shorthand characters inactive as I asked (short of trying to wrap the `otherlanguage` environment)?